# as3 - trying to make a simple search box

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi guys im new to as3 but really love it so would like to continue my journey. Anyway, i am making this search "engine" for a school project and so far all i want it to do is take what the user searched for, search the text document i have for a match, then print it. I have tested the array and it does include the words in the text document so i dont know what im doing wrong. Thanks for any help <3
Heres my code:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
var search:Boolean = false;
var inputText:String;
var arrayResults:Array = new Array();
var array:Array = new Array();
var link:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
link.load(new URLRequest("GameList.txt"))

link.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, linkLoad)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpControl)
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainProgramLoop)

function mainProgramLoop(func:Event):void
{
    if (search == true)
    {
        inputText = input.text
        inputText = inputText.toUpperCase()
    for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputText == String(array[i]))
        {
            arrayResults.push(array[i])
            trace(arrayResults)
        }
    }
}
}

function keyUpControl(func:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (func.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        search = true;
    }
}

function linkLoad(func:Event):void
{
    array = func.target.data.split(",")
}
```

Comment: what is going wrong exactly? you should be getting an array filled with the same word that keeps growing

Comment: it isn't outputing anything

Comment: Use : if (String(array[1]).search(inputText) > 0) ;

Comment: it probably doesn't get to the loop or there's just no match, try tracing for that (or just use a breakpoint)

Comment: hmm it's still now working, how would you guys go about making a search bar?

Comment: `(String(array[i]).search(inputText) > 0)` will match substrings, not sure if that's what you're going for

Comment: it stops tracing after if(inputText == String(array[i])

Comment: well i'll play around with the .search for a bit, thanks for that, lets see if that works :)

Comment: there is no match, are you sure `inputText` in all caps is in your array?

Comment: yeah all the words are in caps in my array and i traced the array just to make sure it was working

Comment: maybe you are inserting a `\n` character when you press enter in your dynamic textField and there is no match

Comment: omg thanks it actually was making a new line haha :P, its working now thanks heaps for the help!